# php validation not working on form submission

Tags: php, html, validation

i am working on a form in which there are few fields and i have applied validation on some fields for eg. name, email and gender, the validation is working fine on the same page but when i click submit it moves to the other page without validating the fields

```
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $pick = $return = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
if (empty($_POST["name"]))
{$nameErr = "* Name is required";}
else
{$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);}
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
 {
 $nameErr = "* Only letters and white space allowed"; 
 }

 if (empty($_POST["email"]))
 {$emailErr = "* Email is required";}
 else
  {
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
 if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
   {
   $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
   }
 }

 if (empty($_POST["gender"]))
{$genderErr = "* Gender is required";}
 else
{$gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);}
}
if (empty($_POST["pick"]))
{$pick = "";}
 else
  {$pick = test_input($_POST["pick"]);}

 if (empty($_POST["return"]))
{$return = "";}
 else
{$return = test_input($_POST["return"]);}

function test_input($data)
 {
 $data = trim($data);
 $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data;
 }
 ?>
```

and heres the html of the form

```
<p><span class="error"></span></p>
<form method="post" action="submit.php<?php echo             htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
E-mail:
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
 <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
<span class="error"><?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
 <br><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="pick"> I would like to specify the Additional                    journey pickups
  <br><br>
  <input type="checkbox"name="return">Return journey required ?<br />
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

any help would b highly appreciated

Comment: Any errors in your error_log? Also, you can use PHP's Email validator using filter_var http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` filter applied. EDIT: Consider cleaning up your indentation on your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: Brr, when i see all this php in the html, i know why i use a template engine if my code gets bigger than 50 lines ... >.< Anyways, if you want to sent something to the page itself, you dont have to specify the action, if its missing, the POST is always send to the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php<?php echo             htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

That line ist wrong. Because `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is your PHP file, so it will be:

```
submit.phpmyphpfile.php
```

Change it to: `<form method="post" action="<?php echo             htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">`

Comment: but i want my form to validate first after validation if all fields are correct then to print the user input on next page by submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behaviour because PHP operates on server-side, so request to given page (eg. page from form `action`) must be performed first. Then PHP will receive values and can validate them. In case of error you can redirect user back to form if you want to and show him what's wrong.

If you want to validate before sending, you should use `JavaScript` but you can't rely on it. User always can skip this validation so you have to use server-side validation even if you used `JavaScript`.

And first of all, you should fix problem which was described by @Legionar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

this line means you post this page to submit.php and submit.php will handle your request
so you may need to add validation  code in submit.php